# Combine multiple xlsx files that contain common sheet names

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, openpyxl

I have a various amount of input .xlsx documents that contain 12 sheets (all sheets have the same name within each .xlsx document). I need to combine these into one .xlsx document while retaining the original sheets' names, but the data from all documents for each sheets appended to the original sheets.

For example, see my original output:

[image]

And the desired output:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
def combine_sheets(self, inputFiles):
    logging.info('combining input files to one spreadsheet')

    '''
    create a pandas excel writer using xlsxwriter as the engine
    pandas and xlsxwriter will need to be installed on server running script
    '''
    outputFile = os.path.join(self.processingDir, 'combined_ncoa_report.xlsx')
    writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(outputFile, engine='openpyxl')

    df = pandas.DataFrame()

    for inputFile in inputFiles:
        logging.info('reading spreadsheet %s' % (os.path.split(inputFile)[-1]))

        # read input xlsx to pandas dataframe
        book = load_workbook(inputFile)
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}

        for sheetname in writer.sheets:
            df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname, startrow=writer.sheets[sheetname].max_row, index = False,header= False)

        writer.save()

    # closing writer
    writer.close()
```

The function is creating the file but it is overwriting the sheet contents each time instead of appending. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: have you tried to print `writer.sheets[sheetname].max_row` in your loop `for sheetname ...` to see if the value is correct?

Comment: The max_row value is being properly populated, but I would think I need  the max row of the sheet in the df that is being populated so it knows where to append the data.

Comment: ok, another comment actually on the code, you do create an empty DF by `df = pandas.DataFrame()` but as far as you show us, you never add anything in this `df` so doing `df.to_excel(...` add nothing to your sheets, am I right?

Comment: I don't think `pandas` is the right tool for this. I would use `xlrd` (http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or similar for this task.

Comment: I believe the df.to_excel(writer....) is what is adding if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I will look at xlrd. I haven't used excel modules in depth at this point.

Comment: @ChadSmith when you do `df.to_excel()` it writes the data from `df` to the excel file, but if your `df` is empty as your code suggest, nothing to add!

Comment: The code is incomplete. It looks like you may be using openpyxl to read the workbooks, in which case I suggest you use it to do all the work.